# Ubuntu 18.04: missing letters in login screen

Tags: login-screen

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 via an USB stick. Everything seemed to work well. But I realized there are some problems, e.g. login window has missing (invisible) letters in words. Photo of login window after restart:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've seen this reported on earlier versions but can't find the duplicate.

Comment: I am also having exactly same problem, and not able to find any solution.

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: I have installed Lubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I'solved this on my machine by editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncommenting:

#WaylandEnable=false

Found this info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1760201

Comment: hmmm. tried it. works kind of. After the second attemt of right credentiales the desktop showed up. The background of the second Monitor is just black. You can see the mouse but no windows are active. After using Menue "Desplays" the driver is resetted and the second monitor ist working.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue.
Settings -> Language and Region -> in upper right corner "Login Screen".
And change Language to English(United Kingdom) and change Formats to United Kingdom.
After this, reboot.
Probably it help you.

Comment: Hi. Thank you in advance. I will try this.

Comment: what language was it before?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, solved by installing the NVidia graphics driver:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`