# login page not showing text and labels ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, login, 17.10, 18.04

I recently upgraded from `ubuntu 17.10` to `ubuntu 18.04`. now every time I want to log in, all labels are missing. log in button has no label, username is not showing and etc. how can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate question, that solution worked for me: [https://askubuntu.com/a/1034235/829343](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034235/829343)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @aleksandrs-t , the solution is right here and worked for me: [[Ubuntu 18.04: missing letters in login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029784/ubuntu-18-04-missing-letters-in-login-screen/1034235#1034235])